# Set iframe height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying fit a iframe that is linked with a search, so i can get a iframe result between 0px and 9750px in height depending on search properties. 
How can i make the height dynamical? I have tried getting the table properties inside the iframe but without success.

Basically i want to know how to get the height of the content I get from the iframe. Not the iframe itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iframeLoaded() {
  var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
  if(iFrameID) {
        // here you can make the height, I delete it first, then I make it again
        iFrameID.height = "";
        iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
     }   
}
</script>
```

When I try to do this i get this eror "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:52191" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: If the frame is on a different domain to the containing page you cannot access the contents to determine the height - as you've discovered from the error you've seen.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there a way to  set the height in any way?  For the moment i have 9750px of whitespace... and that is not optimal

Comment: You can absolutely set the height of the iframe, but you cannot access the content of the cross-domain iframe to know what to set the height to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get the iframe size because **cross domain** issue , but i think this library can solve the problem.
[iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)